# Why is Open question not answerable?

Tags: support, status-completed

[Can you hold two working visas for two separate countries at once?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51833/can-you-hold-two-working-visas-for-two-separate-countries-at-once) has 'history':

Post Reopened by Ankur Banerjee♦    occurred Jul 28 '15 at 15:01
Post Locked by Community♦   occurred Jul 28 '15 at 14:45
Post Migrated Away to expatriates.stackexchange.com by mindcorrosive♦   occurred Jul 28 '15 at 14:45
Post Closed as "off-topic" by mindcorrosive♦    occurred Jul 28 '15 at 14:45
Post Reopened by mindcorrosive♦     occurred Jul 28 '15 at 14:45
Post Closed as "off-topic" by Gayot Fow, pnuts, Nate Eldredge, JoErNanO, Relaxed    occurred Jul 28 '15 at 14:34

It is not Closed but can't be answered.

Comment: Yeah, migration is basically a lock, and locked questions can’t be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@RoflcoptrException♦ has just kindly deleted the Q in question from TSE - it is still available on Expatriates however.

Answer (score 3):

It's migrated, meaning it's shifted to somewhere else in the SE network.

Click through the link and you'll be able to answer it there. But you'll have to make an account there.

Comment: @pnuts i believe that it is there to be another link to the question in expatriates. I can't really think of a reason why lol